# Error message: java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, netbeans, mariadb, mysql-connector

so i have declared an SQL connection like below :

```
public class db {

public void run() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project", "rizkiaswangga", "");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

i'm just trying to connect MariaDB to my Java project firstly, but although i have declared SQLException, i still encounter an error message like below :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

when i try to run from other class :

```
public class Start extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Start
 */
public Start() {
    initComponents();
    db myDb = new db();
    myDb.run();
}
```

what  is wrong on my code? any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In run method you have declared `throws SQLException` but you are not throwing exception. Also in Start method you have not added `throws SQLException`.

Remove `throw SQLException` from `public void run()` method.

```
public class db {

    public void run() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project", "rizkiaswangga", "");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```